# A function that counts how many elements in binary tree of integers have value less that average value of elements of right subtree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am new here.I have a homework which I have no idea how to do.Any help is welcome !

A binary tree of integers is given. Write a function that counts how many elements in tree have a value less than the average value of the elements of right subtree.

Comment: If you can traverse tree, you should find the average in one go and count the nodes in second...

Comment: what did you try so far! share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two special cases to consider:

1. The root is null,
2. The right link of the root is null,

The question doesn't say how to deal with these cases.

Now if neither the root, nor the right link is null, you can compute the average of the right subtree with a complete traversal.

To count the values in a tree that are lower than some parameter x:

- if the root is null, the result is zero,
- if the value of the root is greater or equal that x, ignore the right subtree, the result is the result of the same algorithm applied recursively to the left subtree,
- if the value of the root is less that x, the result is the number of nodes in the left subtree, plus the result of the same algorithm applied recursively to the right subtree